# Fake iOS UI Tools

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, user-experience

I am trying to put together a fake UI for an iOS and Android device without actually creating all that tedious UI work. Is there a way to mockup the UI from the images somehow? We have the Photoshop designs and mockups so far.

Are there any tools? I've checked Titanium and ForgedUI. While its a fairly simple concept I still think its an overkill to create all that. for instance I have to slice my PSD for the buttons. Plus the data feed has to come from a URL etc.

I just want something similar to Balsamiq Mockups linked screens one to another for an actual demo of a bunch of screens. We want to test the navigation, the fonts and the product concept while development is getting the product ready.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say on iOS, the easiest way of doing is, is by just clicking together a storyboard in Interface Builder. That is, as long as you use the normal UI components.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use HTML. If you already have Photoshop mockups, you can simply export those to (retina quality) PNG images and add some image maps for navigation. If you add this site to your homescreen, you will have a pixel-perfect preview without Safari's navigation bar.

However, iOS apps depend heavily on animations. If you're going for a native UI anyway, you should consider creating a "real" UI prototype, using actual `UIControl` elements. While this is more work, it allows for much better UI evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

For wireframing, a couple of options:

1. For high-fidelity mockups, I would do it in Interface Builder and storyboard, like JustSid recommended. Just don't do the tedious work of hooking up the UI elements.
2. You could look at tools like [Adobe Proto](http://www.adobe.com/products/proto.html). I've never tried it, but it seems like it might be an option.
3. For my super-quick, low-fidelity mockups (e.g. digital equivalent of the "back of the envelope" mockups), I personally use my iPad, a [stylus](http://www.wacom.com/en/south-america-home/products/bamboo/bamboostylus), and a drawing package like [Sketchbook Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sketchbook-pro-for-ipad/id364253478?mt=8) (use whatever drawing package you want, but I like one with layers). I also put [blank device images](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html#guidelines) on my iPad, too.

   So, I open up my drawing package on my iPad, start a new drawing using a picture of an iPhone device as the starting point, drop on a new layer (so I can draw on a layer and either hide or discard that layer to instantly get back to the image of the blank device image), and just draw what I want my UI to look like on this new layer. This works great for brainstorming sessions. There's no automatic bridge from this conceptual, low-fidelity mockup to an actual Xcode storyboard, but I can draw a user interface mockup in seconds. I do this not only for brainstorming with designers, but also for fleshing out my own conceptual ideas, myself, too.